# Split a row to create multiple couple

Tags: excel

I'm trying to split a row in excel:

[image: Example of my Excel]

To look like this:

[image: Exemple of my output]

By the way I have a lot of row and column

I'm not very clear, and I don't know how to explain this in a better way

Comment: Have you researched Pivot Tables?  It would get you what you're asking.

Comment: What you want is to **UNPIVOT**.  Search SO for that, or, with Excel 2010+, you can use `Power Query`  or `Data - Get & Transform`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Power Query** it is an add-in that you can download and install easily, in Excel 2016 is a default in **Data** tab:

1. Go to **Power Query** tab or **Data** Tab and select **From Table/Range**. **OK**.

It will open the Query Editor, there:

2. Select `[Numero ID Contacto]`.
3. Go to **Transform** tab and look for **Unpivot Columns**.
4. Select **Unpivot Other Columns**.
5. Go to **Close and Load** in **Home** tab.

It will create a new table with your data transformed.

[image]

I made this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZA_r5aVetU&t=19s). It is in Spanish but I am using the English Excel version.