# Excel Transform Rows to Repeated Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, transform

New here so I appreciate your patience in advance.

I feel like it's a simple question, but it's been boggling me for a while and I can't find a good solution.

I have data like this:
[image: Raw Data]

And I'm trying to make it like this:
[image: Result Data]

Thanks in advance, this problem has been giving me way more grief than I thought it would.

Comment: Which Excel version do you have? Since Excel2010 you can use PowerQuery. It is an add-in for ETL. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425716/split-a-row-to-create-multiple-couple/48426803#48426803) a similar question I answered using unpivot table.

Comment: Thanks, virtualdivid, I'd started trying with PowerQuery, but you made me go back to it and try a few different ways that got me my answer.

Answer (score 0):

2 methods I can suggest:

**Method 1: VBA**

Here is some very simple code VBA that can do what you ask.

It just needs you to establish where the data starts, but then posts it in an adjacent sheet.

There are 3 counters essentially that track where you are within the data set on either sheet.

I am sure there is a more savvy user here that can provide a more succinct answer, but this should put your mindset in the right direction.

This code itterates through each row one value at a time. If you have a very sizable dataset, then this may take a long time.

```
Sub Repeat_Rows()

    Dim iRows As Integer
    Dim iColumns As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim start As Range

    Set start = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    iRows = start.End(xlDown).Row    'find out total rows of initial data
    k = 0

    For i = 1 To iRows

        iColumns = Sheet1.Range("A" & i).End(xlToRight).Column '# columns in the row

        For j = 2 To iColumns 'starts at column B

            k = k + 1 'row counter for sheet 2
            Sheet2.Range("A" & k).Value = Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value
            Sheet2.Range("B" & k).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, j).Value

        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

**Method 2: Pivot Table**

I am honestly not very good with pivot tables myself, but this is definitely a plausible method to use. Just highlight the data, create a pivot table, then play with  the label locations until you get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, Wes, the code worked great.  Unfortunately, it caused an overflow error for the amount of data I needed to use.

Comment: I can understand that, an overflow error occurs when you max out the integer value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to virtualdvid in the comments to leading me the right direction.  Solution is as follows in screenshots:

[image: Get & Transform Data from Table/Range]

[image: Select all rows right of items to be repeated and "Unpivot only selected columns]

[image: Result Data]

It was a simple question after all and I was just over complicating it.  Thanks!